# Nested Query in EF6

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have a query which I like to use for paging.  With dapper I am able to take the query below and use SplitOn which allows me to separate the results on the left side of SplitOn column into one object and results of the right side of SplitOn column into a second object.  What this allows me to do is get a total records count along with records for "specified" pages only

```
SELECT *             
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,1 as SplitOn,
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id )) AS RowNum, COUNT(*) over() as TotalRows
            FROM ( 
                SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM Customer
            ) AS FirstQuery
    ) AS TEMP 
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1 + ((@Page - 1) * @PageSize) AND @Page * @PageSize
```

If you run above in SQL for page 6 you will get:

```
Id FirstName LastName SplitOn RowNum TotalRows
61    John     Luke      1      1      120
62    Jane     Sky       1      2      120
63    Boby     Doe       1      3      120
64    Sam      Ace       1      4      120
65    Dany     Table     1      5      120
etc...
```

I am trying to accomplish the same with EF6 but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to convert that query to an equivalent LinQ Expression.

I realize that SplitOn may not be possible with EF6, so I can work around that with a single object, but I still cannot figure out how to make my query with LinQ.

Comment: Well, there is a thing called table splitting, but you seem to use this feature to separate paging data from the actual payload. In EF you'd simply do that by using `Skip/Take` in a LINQ query and send entities and paging metadata wrapped together in some response object. Or by using the PagedList Nuget package.

Comment: @GertArnold So with Pagination, you often need to know the Total Number of records.  Which usually means you have to query twice.  I have another question on SO that I go more into detail with this.  I am essentially trying to avoid to have to query the database twice.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893646/paging-with-3-sub-qeries-with-1-connection-vs-2-queries-with-2-connections